# Combine group_by() with custom function or operation

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to run a function by groups within my dataframe. The function compares adjacent lines, but should "reset" for each group. I have tried the following:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- as.data.frame(list('x'=1:6,'y'=(1:6)^2,'z'=5:10, 'g'=c(4,4,4,5,5,5),
                          'h'=c('a','a','b','b','c','c')))
df1 <- group_by(df1,h) %>%
  for (i in 2:nrow(df1)) {
    df1$Head.Distance[i] <- with(df1, sqrt((x[i] - x[i-1])^2 + 
                                             (y[i] - y[i-1])^2 +
                                             (z[i] - z[i-1])^2))
  }
```

but this results in a NULL value for `df1`. How can I run this operation on each group? (As a note, the operation should leave the first row `NA` or `0`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be looking for `mutate` and `lag`:

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(h) %>% 
  mutate(xl = (x - lag(x,1))^2,
         yl = (y - lag(y,1))^2)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for!